# What constraint is being violated?

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table, sqlfiddle

I am trying to write an alter table statement in Oracle and using SQLFiddle to test it and am getting a very vague error, so looking for help here. SQLFiddle did find two other errors for me so I assume the error I am seeing is valid.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Space (
  uri                  varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  etag                 varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  title                VARCHAR2(255),
  description          VARCHAR2(4000),
  dependencyResource   varchar(255)
)
```

Here is the alter table statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Space
ADD detectConflict NUMBER(1, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

Here is the error I see:

> ORA-02091: transaction rolled back ORA-02290: check constraint
>   (SYSTEM.DEFERRED_4_D0560_CK) violated

Link to SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0560/2

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05342 Use DDL on the left side

Comment: @Mihai Thanks. If you post your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Eh is just a simple mistake, post it yourself if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a mistake in my understanding of how SQLFiddle works. Mihai pointed out that DDL statements need to all be on the left side.